# Manually trigger change:attribute

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a model `cell` with an attribute `foo`.
I have a listener thats bound to `"change:foo"` like so:

```
cell.listenTo(cell, "change:foo", function(){ 
  if(cell.foo == "bar"){
    doSomething()
  }
});
```

Now, since the listener is bound at a point in time when `foo` may already be `"bar"`, I want to manually trigger `change:foo` in order for the code to run, after the listener is bound. I'm unable to bind the listener earlier due to constraints from my application.

I found a Backbone.js cheat sheet which claimed I could just use `cell.change()` to trigger `change:attribute` for each attribute of the model, but that just yields `Uncaught TypeError: cell.change is not a function`.  I am aware that I can trigger the change event by calling `cell.trigger("change")` but that does not trigger `change:foo`.

I **could** change my listener to listen for `"change"` instead of `"change:foo"` but if it's at all possible I'd like to stick with `"change:foo"` for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an arbitrary string to [`trigger`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-trigger), most notably the event you want, `change:foo`

Try

```
var cell = new Backbone.Model({
    foo: 'bar'
});
cell.on('change:foo', function() {
    console.log('foo changed', cell.get('foo'));
});
cell.trigger('change:foo');
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/tk33rme2/

Comment: Yeah you're right. The problem was with another Framework that sits on top of Backbone and for whatever reasons overwrites the trigger function.